# If $x=a\times \sin(90⁰-n)$, $y=b\cdot \sin(90⁰-m)$, $m+n=t$ then what is the value of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{2xy}{ab}\cdot \cos t+\frac{y^2}{b^2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I need the proof of
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{2xy}{ab}\cdot \cos t+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\sin^2 t$$
I tried to solve the math by using formulas like
\begin{align}
\sin(A+B)=\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B\\
\cos(A+B)=\cos A \cos B — \sin A \sin B
\end{align}

What should I do then to solve this math?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you learnt invere trigonometric functions?

Answer (score -1):

(Edit, sorry I messed up my previous counter example, here is one that does work)
The formula is not true, say for example $n=m=60º$, then
$$\frac{x}{a}= \sin(30)=\frac{1}{2},$$
$$\frac{y}{b}= \sin(30)=\frac{1}{2}$$ and $t=120º$ (that is, $\cos(120º)=-\frac{1}{2}\text{ and }\sin(120º)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$, then on the left hand side you have
$$\frac{1}{4}+(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{1}{2})+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{8}$$
and on the right you have $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: How did you get $t=2$?

Comment: Thanks. After seeing such problem, I was puzzled and figure out no solution. As I am not an expert in math, I decided to show it to someone. Can you give me the right solution with right question? It may be sin²(2×90⁰). Please give the solution of this I mean in case of sin²(2×90⁰). Actually I am a student of class 9.

Comment: @MahdiEnamBorno, what is the right question? is it the title?

Something that may be useful is the fact that $\sin(90º-x)=\cos(x)$ (this comes from the formulas you wrote)

Comment: Yes, I want to know the exact value of the statement.